# ZF2 - Select with CONCAT

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm trying to make a select like this:

> SELECT `c`.*, CONCAT(c.provider_id,'#',c.name") FROM `contact` AS `c`

so, I'm writing something like this...

```
$sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
        $query = $sql->select()
        ->from(array('c' => 'contact'))
        ->columns(array("CONCAT(c.provider_id,'#',c.name"), false)
```

but, result is:

> SELECT ``` c``CONCAT(c.provider_id,'#',c.name ``` AS
>   `CONCAT(c.provider_id,'#',c.name` FROM `contact` AS `c`

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is it the double quote `"` in the wrong place? `->columns(array("CONCAT(c.provider_id,'#',c.name"), false)` should be `->columns(array("CONCAT(c.provider_id,'#',c.name)", false)`

Comment: Check out `Zend\Db\Sql\Expression`. I'm outta time, but i guess this can get you started ;)

Comment: Thanks for reply!
SERPIO, you're right that there were an syntax mistake. 
@Sam, you're right too, man! The answer is 

`->columns(array('*',new Expression("CONCAT(c.provider_id,'#',c.name) as data")));`

Comment: You should add your answers as an actual answer to help people find it :-)

Answer (score 3):

When i have to extract some columns from a table and add a Sql function, i usually use this code:

```
$sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
$query = $sql->select()
    ->from(array('c' => 'contact'))
    ->columns(array(
        'id', 'name', 'data' => new Expression('CONCAT(c.provider_id,'#',c.name)')
    )
);
```

`Expression` is an instance of `Zend\Db\Sql\Expression`, the result is:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`,  CONCAT(c.provider_id,'#',c.name) AS `data` FROM `contact` AS `c`
```

Answer (score 2):

check out Database Expressions if you need to use MySQL functions or anything else which you don't want to be escaped automatically for you. some examples:

https://github.com/ralphschindler/Zend_Db-Examples

```
$sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
$query = $sql->select()
    ->from(array('c' => 'contact'))
    ->columns(array(
        '*', new Expression("CONCAT(c.provider_id,'#',c.name) as data")
    ))
;
```